# How do I add JS include to the bottom of </body> in GatsbyJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

How do I add JS to the bottom of GatsbyJS?  I'm new to React and Gatsby and need help with clear instructions.  I don't have an index.html file with `</body>` visible anywhere in my /src folder.  The script I would like to add is jQuery and a few other jQuery libraries that should only load after the content has been loaded.

Comment: Have you generated your website? You can run `gatsby build` to create the website with a root html. But it’s not recommended ti use jQuery with React!

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54468240/how-to-include-jquery-in-a-gatsby-js-project

Comment: @Kokodoko when built, a Gatsby site is a set of pure static files and, so on, React shouldn't be included in the production folder. jQuery can then be used as a front-end framework, don't you think ?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, You have to use Jquery in your case, but best practices is avoid using JQuery because JQuery so slow.

With your question, I think the first, you should do with Gatsby tutorial to understand How Gatsby run/build and work.

After that, you can use either solution below to add custom script to your page:
1. Require directly your script file.
2. Use Helmet plugins
3. Use dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Some link will help you:

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3083
[add raw HTML with <script> inside Gatsby React page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48966464/add-raw-html-with-script-inside-gatsby-react-page)

Regards.

Comment: I don't think using jQuery could be considered bad practice. It's not always the best choice for sure, but one could find meaningful uses.
In addition, I think your tips cannot fall into the "clear instructions" OP asked for ("step 1: read Gatsby doc" ...).