# embed third party script tag in a gatsby.js website

Tags: reactjs, widget, gatsby

I am trying to use a widget in a gatsby.js site but cant find a way of creating a react component that works!

```
<div>
  <script src="https://widgets.bookalet.co.uk/publish.js" data-bookalet="b41d3564-11ba-4a54-9ee2-b7d6ec55b214" data-property="13563"></script>
</div>
```

This is what the widget looks like. Its the data-bookalet and data-property attributes that seem to be the anomalies I cant find answers to!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include jQuery in a Gatsby.js project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54468240/how-to-include-jquery-in-a-gatsby-js-project)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using React Helmet and implementing it something like this:

```
<Helmet>
    <script>
        {`YOUR_SCRIPT_HERE`}
    </script>
</Helmet>
```

Source: [react-helmet documentation](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) and [gatsby-plugin-react-helmet](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/)