# Problem with jquery(react-owl-carousel) in gatsby/react

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

please help. I was trying to use react-owl-carousel in a gatsby site but I have run into a problem. The error says:

[image]

Here's my `gatsby-node.js`

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ plugins, actions }) => {
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    plugins: [
      plugins.define({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      }),
    ],
  })
}
```

Comment: is it plugins or externals in your WebPackConfig? I followed the recommendation here and works like charm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54468240/how-to-include-jquery-in-a-gatsby-js-project

Answer (score 2):

try this in your gatsby-node.js

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions }) => {
  const { setWebpackConfig } = actions
  setWebpackConfig({
    externals: {
      jquery: 'jQuery', // important: 'Q' capitalized
    },
  })
}
```

and in html.js

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export default function HTML(props) {
  return (
    <html {...props.htmlAttributes}>
      <head>
        <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
        />
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta httpEquiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
        />
        {props.headComponents}
      </head>
      <body {...props.bodyAttributes}>
        {props.preBodyComponents}
        <div
          key={`body`}
          id="___gatsby"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.body }}
        />
        {props.postBodyComponents}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

HTML.propTypes = {
  htmlAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  headComponents: PropTypes.array,
  bodyAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  preBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
  body: PropTypes.string,
  postBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
}
```

put html.js in the src folder